# Troubles with ggplot and geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here the updated example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rep(c("A","B"),each=10),
                 b=rep(rep(c("C","D"),each=5),2),
                 c=c(sample(letters[1:5]), sample(letters[6:10]),           
                     sample(letters[1:5]), sample(letters[6:10])),
                 d=c(0.10,0.18,0.34,0.35,0.59,0.16,0.38,0.40,0.53,0.58,
                     0.37,0.62,0.83,1.46,-0.91,-0.79,-0.52,-0.43,-0.01,0.34))

> df
   a b c     d
1  A C b  0.10
2  A C e  0.18
3  A C a  0.34
4  A C c  0.35
5  A C d  0.59
6  A D i  0.16
7  A D j  0.38
8  A D h  0.40
9  A D f  0.53
10 A D g  0.58
11 B C e  0.37
12 B C d  0.62
13 B C a  0.83
14 B C c  1.46
15 B C b -0.91
16 B D f -0.79
17 B D i -0.52
18 B D h -0.43
19 B D j -0.01
20 B D g  0.34
```

If you look closely, you will see that column d is ordered within column b always from smallest to largest.

The first plot is how I would like to have the plot apart from the fact, that the bars displayed are not in the order of d. So the bars do not appear from smallest to largest:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=c, y=d, fill=b, stat="identity")) +

facet_grid(. ~ a) +

geom_bar()  

print(p)
```

[image: barplot1]

This is because column c is a factor and the factors are apparently not ordered in the same order as column d is. So I did the following:

```
df$c <- paste(1:nrow(df), df$c, sep="_")

df$c <- factor(df$c, levels = unfactor(df$c))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=c, y=d, fill=b, stat="identity")) +

            facet_grid(. ~ a) +

            geom_bar()  

print(p)
```

produces the following plot:

[image]

Here the order is correct. However, as you can see I created unique factors I get those spaces for the ones not present in A and B respectively.

How can I sort that out?

Comment: In this case, the warning can be ignored.  You are not technically stacking bar plots anyway.  I don't know if you can block the warning.

Comment: If you just want the warning to go away, see `suppressWarnings()`. Or you can control when warnings are displayed at a more global level using `options()` (but that's probably not a good idea, since it would suppress all warnings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have changed the question, 'ggplot' cannot do this for you.  By giving [df$c] levels, you could order the data but only based on the first set of [c] values.  For instance:

```
df$c <- factor(df$c, levels=levels(df$c)[order(df$d)])
```

But that won't work, since you're trying to sort [df$c] twice (once for "A", and once for "B").

You really need to break this into two separate plots, and just plot the two viewports next to each other.

**Setting up the viewports**:

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
```

**Plot A**:

```
a_df <- df[df$a=="A",]
a_df$c <- factor(a_df$c, levels=levels(a_df$c)[order(a_df$d)])

a_p <- ggplot(a_df, aes(x=1:10, y=d, fill=b)) +
facet_grid(. ~ a) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

print(a_p, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1))
```

**Plot B**:

```
b_df <- df[df$a=="B",]
b_df$c <- factor(b_df$c, levels=levels(b_df$c)[order(b_df$d)])

b_p <- ggplot(b_df, aes(x=1:10, y=d, fill=b)) +
facet_grid(. ~ a) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")

print(b_p, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=2))
```

From here, you can worry about removing the excess legend, choosing which axes to label and such, but it looks exactly like your example plot only with the empty locations removed.

This is really an example of how 'ggplot' is sometimes more of a hindrance and less of a boon.  In my experience, it's best to first design your plot and then choose the tool.  Frequently, I find myself going back to raw 'grid' to do my visuals, because I want something the 'grid' wrapper 'ggplot' just won't do.

Note: In the future, don't delete your original question content; just add the updated info.  Removing the old content makes a lot of the answers and comments on this page irrelevant.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort to produce this nice answer. I tried even more but it really looks like that ggplot isn't able to handle that situation. I will, therefore, just go for your solution and adjust axes, legends etc by hand in illustrator or so. Thanks anyway. good solution! :) And, yes, I can see that now answers given do not make any sense anymore since I deleted the original question. Is not going to happen again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually a common mistake with the 'ggplot' function.  If you set an outline color (i.e. `aes(colour="red")`), you will see that you are actually plotting all four values, but they are plotting on top of each other.  The stacking warning is because the default value of 'position' is "stack".  Just include the `position="dodge"` argument, and that will go away.

Now, to actually solve your problem.  You need to give 'ggplot' something to distinguish between the values of X(A), X(B), Y(A), and Y(B).  At first glance, you might be tempted to use your [b] values, but you don't want all of the extra spaces.  Let's adjust your dataframe to have only 1s and 2s for [b]:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rep(rep(c("A","B"),each=2),2), 
b=rep(1:2,4), 
c=rep(c("X","Y"),each=4), 
d=c(1.2,1.1,1.15,1.1, -1.1,-1.05,-1.2,-1.08))
```

The plot is actually pretty easy to fix once you know the problem.  First, set [b] to your x-axis, and add [a] to your facet.  Then remove all of the annoying gibberish from [b] using the 'theme' with blank elements:

```
p <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x=b, y=d)) +      
facet_grid(. ~ c + a) +
geom_bar(data = df, stat="identity", position="dodge") +
theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())

print(p)
```

If this isn't exactly what you want, it should be at least close enough that you'll only have to do cosmetic changes.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey, I just tried your example but it does not work for me. It says cannot find theme and if I comment it out then it works but the result is not as expected

Comment: I just tried it again, and it still works.  Perhaps there's an issue elsewhere?  Try copy-pasting directly from the example, and if that doesn't work, update your 'ggplot2' package to the latest.  If you still have problems, give info on your OS, R install, and what process you're using, and maybe we can find your problem.  The 'theme' function is part of 'ggplot2', so I'm a bit confused why you are getting an error.

Comment: `theme()` was introduced in a recent update of ggplot2, so the OP likely is using an older version.

Comment: I'm guessing they're after `fill = factor(b)` and then adding `position = "dodge"` inside `geom_bar`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This is where having a sample sketch would come in handy.  With a sketch of the proposed graph, we could skip all this guessing.

Comment: I am just updating all of my R packages and yes there is a new ggplot package available. I created a better example so is it better to create a new thread for it or just update my original question to the new example? Not sure how this is handled here?

Comment: Update your current question.

Comment: When I said "update," perhaps I should have been more specific.  Don't delete your old content.  Just add the update(s).